# View center mode in react native swiper?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am using react native swiper, to show some slide show. It works fine. But i want the center mode that a view must be show in center and other views from left and right should be visible little bit  like carousal.

**here is my Sample slide ..**

[image: **Sample carousal**]

here we can see little bit of prev and next slides. So like this i want to show. I tried some ways , but not getting anything

**here is my code ..**

```
<View style={styles.text}>
    <Carousel 
        pageStyle={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            padding: 5,
            width:180,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            marginHorizontal:-30
        }}>
        <View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image source={ logo } style={styles.picture} />
            </View>
        </View>  
        <View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image source={ logo } style={styles.picture} />
            </View>
        </View>  
        <View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image source={ logo } style={styles.picture} />
            </View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image source={ logo } style={styles.picture} />
            </View>
        </View>
        <View>
            <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
                <Image source={ logo } style={styles.picture} />
            </View>
        </View>
    </Carousel>
</View>
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel

Comment: remove this padding: 5, from pageStyle and keep width : '100%', Not static

Comment: @KiritModi its not working

Comment: 'react-native-snap-carousal' - this is what i am using...But not getting @keshav